# When using ALTER COLUMN to change the field dimensions, what constraints are lost unless also explicitly included in the statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, alter

I am writing some code to automatically **ALTER COLUMN** dimensions in a target table where neccessary to accomodate the data of a source table prior to INSERTing into it.

For example, say I have a source table containing a column called **ABC** defined as **VARCHAR(10)**.
I have a target table with that column defined as **VARCHAR(5)**.
I want to **INSERT** the source data into the target table.
So, if the column in the source table has a maximum *populated* data length in excess of the **5** characters allowed for in the target table, I resize the target column.
I can then safely **INSERT** from the source into the target without truncation errors.

Along the way I have discovered that any columns being re-sized that had the **NOT NULL** constraint on them will lose it unless I explicitly add it to the **ALTER COLUMN** statement.
I can determine this via the **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS** table, so that is easy enough to deal with.

The issue of course is that I *just* want to change the column *dimensions* (length/precision/scale) and preserve everything else - so what about other constraints - **PRIMARY KEY**, **DEFAULT**, **CHECK**, etc. ?
Which of these, if any, must I also re-state as part of the **ALTER COLUMN** statement?

The **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS** table only seems to have the information about the **NULL** constraint (in the **IS_NULLABLE** column) - where would I acquire the other constraints I would need to re-state?

Comment: No `CONSTRAINT`s are lost when you `ALTER` a column, however, often you *can't* `ALTER` a column unless you first `DROP` that `CONSTRAINT` (and then you need to recreate it). The `NULL`ability of a column isn't a `CONSTRAINT`; it's part of the data type definition.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you.  I thought they were 'constraints' as almost all of the Google search results from "t-sql null constraint" explicitly use the phrase "NULL constraint".  Ok, so apart from the NULL ability of a column, are there any other properties I would need to re-state in the ALTER COLUMN statement?

Comment: Also, apologies, I can't seem to add line breaks, either with double-spaces at the end of a line or <br/> as per [Stackoverflow comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - any advice?

Comment: `NOT NULL` is a bit weird. You can do `CREATE TABLE #T (X INT CONSTRAINT SomeName NOT NULL)` but this doesn't actually create a separate constraint object called "SomeName" - it just sets a column property

Comment: *"I can't seem to add line breaks"* The line breaks in your question are appearing fine for me, @SquidNet .

Comment: Regarding the `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` - "ANSI_NULL defaults are always on for ALTER COLUMN; if not specified, the column is nullable." this is why you have to be explicit and it doesn't preserve the previous nullability.

Comment: You can test this yourself. Only primary keys and foreign keys need to be dropped and recreated. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b270da89885bb408ff19df15d3688e51

Comment: Looks like `SPARSE` is another property that can be lost in this way https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64299bd44dfae20395bfcb12d4d0457d - probably just look at the properties in `sys.columns` and test them all. e.g. I have no idea if `ROWGUIDCOL` would be preserved on ALTER unless stating it.

Comment: The [collation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39c44fd62055fe227dcb0ad0f582a404) is also lost, @MartinSmith . I'd suggest anything in the `<column_definition>` section in the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), that doesn't create a separate object (like a `CONSTRAINT`) is subject to be "defaulted" on an `ALTER`.

Comment: @MartinSmith As does `MASKED` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d483dec2acd13357cfe3ae9368c47e6a Looks like the relevant grammar in `ALTER TABLE` is incorrect. I also get a weird error if I try to add it back https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91eedb51d1bd11a319f497278885cd12

Comment: Thanks so much all! The 'simple' task of automating column expansion has become a lot more complicated!  As an alternative approach, is there a way I can emulate the `SCRIPT TABLE AS > CREATE TO` output so that I can get that script into a string?  I believe the output from this includes everything, contraints and all (please correct me if I'm wrong)...   If it is possible, then all I would need to do is process that string - drop the columns I am not changing, change the syntax into the `ALTER...COLUMN` form for the remainder, and replace the size numbers with my new ones...

Comment: Use the SMO classes in C#, they can generate these scripts